# Property re-evaluation in .NET C# property

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have the below property that calculates the sum of a list of integers.

```
public int OpponentTotalSetPoints => TeamPoints.Skip(1).Sum(t => t);
```

My questions is does this property get recaculated every time its called?  If so would it be beneficial for the below code to store the value so the summing doesn't happen every time its called?

```
 private int? opponentTotalSetPoints;
        public int OpponentTotalSetPoints
        {
            get
            {
                if (opponentTotalSetPoints.HasValue)
                    return opponentTotalSetPoints.Value;

                opponentTotalSetPoints = TeamPoints.Skip(1).Sum(t => t);

                return opponentTotalSetPoints.Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Consider using `Lazy<T>` to cache the result, or compute it in the ctor.

Comment: It does get recalculated. Whether it is beneficial depends on many factors, and you should test the performance yourself.

Comment: What is the type of `TeamPoints`? If it’s `IQueryable<T>` to EF then you should definitely **not** be doing that in a property-getter. But an in-memory `IEnumerable<T>` is fine, though.

Comment: If TeamPoints is doing database operations then it is fine to store the value in some object else it won't affect much.

Comment: Its a standard List<int>

Comment: @MikeFlynn Is the `List<int>` mutable?

Comment: The list doesnt change, basically readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be using something like this

```
        private int? opponentTotalSetPoints;
        public int OpponentTotalSetPoints
        {
            get
            {
                if (opponentTotalSetPoints==null)
                   if (TeamPoints.Count >1)
                       opponentTotalSetPoints = TeamPoints.Skip(1).Sum(t => t);

                return opponentTotalSetPoints;
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1) it will throw for `TeamPoints == null`  and `TeamPoints.Count() <= 1` 2) `Count` is not needed either way.

Comment: @GuruStron I am sorry,  I am adding it  just to be on the safe side.  Sometimes it can cause null reference  at the start. I don't know how this property  is used since I can't see any code at all.

Comment: TeamPoints is never null, but an empty list or more.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you, you are right. I am sorry ,  it was typo i fixed my code

Comment: @MikeFlynn  thank you, it was typo i fixed my code